# integrate kdb/q with BI tools

Tags: kdb

how to integrate kdb/q with  BI tools like cognos to create visualizations and graphs.
I have some historical data in KDB database and i want to plot trends using cognos BI tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no out-of-the box way of doing this as you won't be able to use the normal database connectors that come with these types of BI tools (they would have ODBC, etc). A very hairy option is simply to batch up a copy of the data in KDB to an SQL database that Cognos understands. Obvious disadvantages there.

I don't really know much about Cognos, but there seems to be some plugin development in the applications - maybe you can use the c# or c++ api to kdb to pass data along to the BI application.

EDIT

panopticon.com have some really funky data visualisations, if that's all you want.. Saw a demo once, very cool.

EDIT 2

I really should read questions more thoroughly :) Re trends, why not simply use R or the very many graphing applications for which you can have C# plugins? With R trending etc becomes an easy process. If you prefer Excel, you can interface with KDB directly (http://code.kx.com/q/interfaces/excel-client-for-q/)

Comment: The link for Panopticon's kx UI: http://www.panopticon.com/Kx-Tick-Databases-and-CEP-Engines

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the JDBC driver with Cognos BI tools. Simply:

1. Download the driver http://code.kx.com/q/interfaces/jdbc-client-for-kdb/
2. Configure the [driver in Cognos](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cbi/v10r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.cognos.c8pp_inst.10.1.0.doc/c8pp_inst_id3996SetUpDBConnectivityForContentStore_sing.html).

Almost any BI tools that allow a jdbc will in fact work. If you are looking for charting that works out of the box with kdb try qStudio/sqlDashboards http://www.timestored.com/sqldashboards/ .
DISCLAIMER - I work for the company that produces the software. You can download a free version that allows charting kdb results etc.